# MS SQL Cannot bulk load because the file ... error code 5(Access is denied)

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL server `DOMAIN\DB` running under a domain service account `DOMAIN\svc_sql`. If I run a script accessing a file in a network share from another server `DOMAIN\CLIENT` connecting to `DOMAIN\DB` using SSMS authenticated by my domain account `DOMAIN\user`, I got this error

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\FILE_SHARE\file.json" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
```

Both of `DOMAIN\svc_sql` and `DOMAIN\user` have access to this file. Also, this problem does not occur if I RDP and SSMS with my `DOMAIN\user` into `DOMAIN\DB`.

From what I found, this might be something regarding double-hop issue and delegation.

My SPN seems to be correct:

```
C:\Users\user>setspn -L DOMAIN\svc_sql
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=svc_sql,DC=DOMAIN,DC=pvt:
        MSSQLSvc/DB.DOMAIN.pvt:1433
        MSSQLSvc/DB.DOMAIN.pvt
```

I tried to set the service account `DOMAIN\svc_sql` to be trusted for delegation of any services and reboot `DOMAIN\DB`, but it still does not work.

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ADUser svc_sql -Properties TrustedForDelegation,TrustedToAuthForDelegation

....
TrustedForDelegation       : True
TrustedToAuthForDelegation : False
UserPrincipalName          : svc_sql@DOMAIN
```

Comment: If you assume it's a kerberos issue, you can always double check with the Microsoft Kerberos Configuration manager, this gives a clear overview of SPN/Delegation issues.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Comment: Thank you. This tool helps to visualize a lot. Come down resolution is to I have to add specific file server with cifs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have to set **constrained delegation** of the cifs protocol.

[image]

Comment: In the wild world of Microsoft, this fixed it. I have to add my file server with cifs